# How can I split Angular property strings and use multiples of these property types together instead of using nested ng-repeat directives?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, excel

Instead of creating an array inside of a property in Angular and using ng-repeat for each item in the array, I am interested in setting a property as a string and looping through each item by comma. The problem is that for each iteration, or key, I am also interested in grabbing the corresponding email address. The reason I am interested in using a single string for multiple values instead of an array is because I am converting Microsoft Excel files into JSON files. Unless there is an easier way of formatting an excel file so that a converter can convert these values into an array rather than a string I need to know how I can create some kind of service, filter, or reorganization of my code to solve this problem of looping through a string rather than an array.

The original formatting of the collection data:

```
{
    "date": "February 2016",
    "names": ['name - title', 'name2 - title 2', name3 - title 3'],
    "year": 5,
    "emails": ['email@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com']
},
```

New formatting of collection data converted from xls to JSON:

```
{
    "date": "February 2016"
    "names": "name - title, name2 - title 2, name3 - title 3",
    "year": 5,
    "emails": "email@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com"

}
```

Below is my HTML corresponding with the above data. This object is referenced under **$scope.anns**:

```
<section ng-repeat="names in anns | filter: {date:dateText}">
<p><b class="ng-cloak">{{names.year}} Years</b></p>
<p ng-repeat="name in names.names track by $index ">{{name}} - filter </p>
<p ng-repeat="email in names.emails" class="ng-cloak"><a href="mailto:{{name.emails}}">{{email}}</a></p>
</section>
<p ng-repeat="name in names.names track by $index ">{{name}} - filter </p>
```

I also began working on a filter that I could use to seperate the values by comma and add these into a new array.

```
angular.module('main').filter('commaArray', function() {
return function(data)
{
    var output = []; 
    angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){
        output.push(value); 
        console.log(output);
    })
    return output; 
}
});
```

In my case I do not have to use this filter, however my main issue is that I cannot create a ng-repeat directive inside of another ng-repeat directive as this creates unwanted results such that I am getting multiple sets of items instead of one unique name at a time. I've also tried to using the track by $index, however this still creates unwanted results. Can you help me see were I am going wrong or what I need to do to improve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter should use `split()` to convert the string to array, e.g.:

```
angular.module('main').filter('commaArray', function() {
    return function(data) {
        return data == null ? [] : data.split(',').map(function(s) {
            return s.trim(); // check that the browsers you want to support support trim(), or use a stock trim function, e.g. from jQuery
        });
    };
});
```

Use it as (NOTE THE PARENTHESES):

```
<p ng-repeat="email in (names.emails | commaArray)" ...>...</p>
```

Comment: This function tells me that data.split is not a function

Comment: You have to take care that the expression passed to the filter (here `names.emails`) points to the `emails` field. You are probably confusing the data paths in your app, use the filter with some plain data to check.

Comment: This works for one of of the arrays but does not match correctly with the emails field. I want to loop through each name and attach an email to that name.